# Wordpress: Iterate through multiple api fetches within for each loop. Only returns response for first array item

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, foreach, fetch

This issue is happening on a wordpress theme. In short, I previously was iterating through an array of id's and doing a wp_remote_get to an external api for each id. It worked but created page load issues, so refactoring to use ajax and now the wp_remote_get only works on first array item. Here's an example of how the API url is structured:
`http://example-api-url/is-available&id={id}`

My PHP file has a foreach loop that does a wp_remote_get for each id. The remote get is sent to the JS file, which returns a true or false for that ID. Ultimately, I'd like to return an array of ID's that return a true response from the remote fetch.

Now that I'm using the Ajax set up, the api call seems to work, but only on the first ID in the array.

I've tried sending the array of id's to the JS file and looping through them there with the intention of returning the new array of id's returning a true value. The problem here was with the ajax url,  adding the &id= parameter to the ajaxUrl kept returning 403 errors.

I've also tried having the check_test() function set up to take an ID as a parameter and not include a loop, then set up a second function that runs check_test() within a loop. I'm not sure why doing a remote get using AJAX only works on the first array item, where previously, the remote_get worked on each item.

In this example, I'm expecting to see 4 console log messages of true or false; the response for each ID, but I'm only seeing one.

My next idea was to try to set up unique nonces for each array item, but don't know if I'm barking up the right tree. Any advice is appreciated!

```
function check_test( ) {
if ( 1 !== wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['nonce'], 'check-test' ) ) {
status_header( 403 );
die( esc_html( get_status_header_desc( 403 ) ) );
}

$cache_key = 'check-test-' . wp_rand();
$data = get_transient( $cache_key );

$ids = [ '1234', '3215', '1110', '0191' ];

foreach ( $ids as $id ) :
$response = wp_remote_get( "http://example-api-url/is-available&id=
" . $id );

  if ( 200 === wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) ) {
    $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
  } else {
    $data = '';
  }

  set_transient( $cache_key, $data, HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

  echo $data; 
  exit;

  endforeach;

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_test', 'check_test' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_test', 'check_test' );
```

This is what the Javascript file looks like:

```
runCheck() {

const url = `${window.checkTest.ajaxUrl}?action=check_test&nonce=${window.checkTest.nonce}`;
    return fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.text();
        }
        return false;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if ('true' === data) {
          console.log('true');
        } else if ('false' === data) {
          console.log('false');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (console && console.error) { // eslint-disable-line no-console
          console.error(err); // eslint-disable-line no-console
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, while refactoring, I had accidentally added my endforeach; AFTER the exit; Helps to access the whole array when you don't exit early :(